# Django receiving data from UDP and storing in DB, only if condition coming from websockets set to true

Tags: django, websocket, udp, celery, twisted

I'm trying to implement a rather complex architecture for a desktop application (not to be distributed, so it's ok to use technology usually adopted for servers - please don't tell me to use electron or .NET).

It basically must store data coming from a UDP stream (with  new data frequency at ~90Hz). The application should also open a websocket server and accept new clients, specifically from a tablet. The tablet user should be able to set a flag, enabling or disabling data storage.

[This is a very simple block scheme of the system](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qH5Xl4WCW7Dc0Mnoq2Y1fF98yLKs99PP)

I already used Django before, but for more standard usage (CMS, REST APIs, etc). After some research, I found some tools I could use to build the system:

1 - **Celery**, which to my understanding enables running asynchronous tasks (I guess I could use it to store the data coming from the UDP stream, maybe after accumulating a hundred values or so)

2 - **Django channels**, which should help me in the websocket communication

3 - **Twisted**, to receive UDP messages.

What confuses me is how to integrate these components, and exchange data between them. Looks like twisted is a completely separated server, so how can i run a celery task that takes input as data and writes it to a django model?

How should I implement the flag coming from webosckets? global variable?

any help appreciated!

Comment: Forget about Celery and Django channels for now.  Just use Twisted and the well-integrated-with-Twisted-websockets-library Autobahn.  Once you have a better idea of how Twisted works, *if you still think you need it*, then start thinking about how you might integrate Celery (or Django channels, I suppose).  Nothing in the question suggests to me you need more than Twisted, though.

Comment: Actually I omitted to say that the saved data should be served with REST APIs along with other entities in the db, hence the need for Django. The flag state change itself should be saved as event